# I Want to Add Widgets Dynamically with Provider

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using Provider package, and I want to dynamically add widgets to display.
I wrote the code like below, but the widgets doesn't show anything.
No errors have occurred.

```
// Contains widget and related data
class WidgetData {
    Widget? child;  // want to show this
    String data1;
    int data2;
}    

class Model exteds ChangeNotifier {
    List<WidgetData> widget;   // I want to show all of this widget.child
    
    void addWidget(Widget child) {
        print("Called1") // "Called1"
        var w = widgets.toList();
        w.add(child);
        widgetData = w;
        notifyListeners();
    }
}

class Example extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    build (BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: Column(children: [
                 for(var i in context.watch<Model>().widget) i.child!;
        ]);
    }
}
```

When the button pushed, `context.read<Model>().addWidget(Text("test"))` will be called.
But still doesn't show widgets.

```
 // inside of build(BuildContext context)
 FloatingActionButton(
   onPressed: () => context.read<Model>().addWidget(Text("test")),
   child: Icon(Icons.abc)
 );
```

Of course I built the tree of provider in `main`.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
     ChangeNotifierProvider<Model>(
       create: (_) => Model()),
  ));

  child: 
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is discouraged to create and store Widgets outside of the build function in Flutter. Your provider should not provide Widgets, but the data needed to construct widgets, and you then construct the widgets inside the `build` method.

For example, if instead of a list of Widgets you had a list of Strings, then in the `build` method you convert that list of Strings easily into `Text` widgets like this: `Column(children: stringlist.map((e) => Text(e)).toList())`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But how about when widgets are not only Text, like icon, text, container?
How to add widgets inside Column with Provider?

Comment: Presumably all those widget types can be generated conditionally based on some data - even a simple true/false on whether or not to show it. The point here is that Provider and Streams are meant to carry data, not widgets - you build the widgets in the build function when new data comes in, and the logic of what widget to build (based on the data) is what you put in the build function.